# Boot windows from grub rescue command prompt

Tags: linux, windows, grub, rescue

Previously I had installed the Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7.

Now I logged on to Windows, opened the partition editor and deleted the volume containing the Ubuntu - I thought it will delete the Ubuntu and it might help me install another OS - and I restarted the system.

GRUB rescue prompt is there.

I want to log on to Windows. How can I do that?

In GRUB rescue, I tried the following:

```
ls
(hd0) (hd0,3) (hd0,2) (hd0,1) (hd1) (hda1,1)
```

Tried all combinations of `ls (hdax)/`, which threw out:

```
error: Unknown Filesystem.
```

I tried this:

```
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
makeactive
boot
```

It threw out:

```
Unknown command.
```

EDIT:

I installed Ubuntu from the USB. Now when I restarted the system, I got the GRUB, showing old Windows and the newly installed Ubuntu. I happily logged onto Windows. Then I used standard procedure to remove Ubuntu, so as not to have grub rescue.

Answer (score 43):

You can't boot Windows from a grub rescue prompt, unless the partition with the grub modules is available. That's why you get the unknown command error. Your best solution is to reinstall the Windows bootloader. To do this boot from a Windows 7 repair CD or the Windows Installation DVD to a repair prompt and run:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

If you don't have a Windows repair CD or Installation DVD, it's also possible to install a Windows-like bootloader from an Ubuntu CD/USB if you have one of those:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Note that `lilo` will popup a large warning screen, but it's safe to ignore it as this refers to when it's used to boot linux.

This is what it looks like to use `lilo` (note the command is case-sensitive):

```
bcbc@neptune:~$ sudo apt-get install lilo
[sudo] password for bcbc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  lilo-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lilo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 807 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu/ precise/main lilo amd64 1:23.2-2 [275 kB]
Fetched 275 kB in 1s (198 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package lilo.
(Reading database ... 505850 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking lilo (from .../lilo_1%3a23.2-2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up lilo (1:23.2-2) ...
bcbc@neptune:~$ sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
Backup copy of /dev/sda in /boot/boot.0800
The Master Boot Record of  /dev/sda  has been updated.
bcbc@neptune:~$
```

You'll see a warning that looks like this - it can be ignored when you use `lilo` as a windows-style bootloader:

[image]

Comment: How do you boot from a Windows 7 install CD to a repair prompt? If I boot from the install CD, my only option is to install Windows.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Try this: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/start-the-windows-7-recovery-environment/

Comment: Ah, I got it. Once you hit 'Next' like you're about to install Windows, the next screen has the option to repair Windows and then enter the command prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I have the same problem. I do not have the Windows installation DVD and I do not know why I can't boot from USB, even if I force the boot order from BIOS I still get the grub rescue prompt... What could you advise me to do?

Comment: Thank you man, you saved my day!!! I was able to resolve using lilo. Thanks for such a great tool!

Comment: This lilo is a life saver!

Comment: I spent 5 hours today trying every answer here. This is the only thing that worked! For anyone trying this from Windows and getting the errors "Failure when attempting to copy boot files" or "Element not found", follow these two steps and you'll have a working system again.

Comment: Wow! It worked so easy! From the deepest of my heart I have to say: God bless the people who developed lilo and God bless you @bcbc!

Comment: Finally, a legitimate use for lilo!  I miss the little linux loader.  BTW this works form the GParted live disk also, after you update your packages.

Comment: I had similar problem and I asked a question here.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462562/how-do-i-recover-after-failed-instalation-of-grub-efi-amd64-signed

By "sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr" I was able to boot back to windows. I can fix Linux later as it's secondary OS! Thanks

Comment: I booted from a repair drive, ran `bootrec /fixmbr`, and i still get put into grub rescue

Comment: After this I am getting "No partition active". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

If the partition holding `grub` files was deleted, you should be able to boot into Windows using a linux *liveCd* or *liveUSB*, using the option `Boot existing OS` (or `Boot from Local Drive` - most liveUSBs have a similar option).

E.g.: using Archlinux USB, select the option to boot an existing OS:

[image]

then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and point the chain-loader to the windows partition:

[image]

Description of `comboot/chain.c32` usage on [Syslinux page](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Comboot/chain.c32)

Comment: Unknown command 'chainloader'.

Comment: @user7543 - that means you're at `grub rescue` prompt (the linux partition holding the grub files was probably deleted). You'll have to try my second method (via arch liveUSB) or follow `bcbc` instructions in the other post.

Comment: The `grub rescue` prompt has a very limited and unique set of commands not are not at all intuitive to figure out. More [details on working at the `grub rescue` prompt can be found here.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash/148042#148042)