# How to start a windows partition from the Grub command line

Tags: linux, grub

I have Windows 10 HOME installed on my system. After I installed Windows 10 HOME, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a separate partition so that I could dual boot.

I removed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by deleting the partition it was installed on. Now I am unable to start my system. At boot, my system stops at the Grub command line.

I want to boot to my Windows 10 installation which I haven't removed from my system.

This is displayed at startup:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3 <br> 
minimal BASH-like editing is supported.for the first word, TAB lists
possible commands completions.anywhere else TAB lists the possible device or file completion.
grub>
```

How can I boot my Windows partition from this grub command?

Answer (score 72):

The following worked for me with a GPT partitioned disk.

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod chain
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
```

Note that you can enter a command line from the grub boot menu and just type commands as above to test out different combinations.

You need to enter the id of the EFI boot partition (not the windows partition) for the `set root=` command.

In the command line grub mode  `ls` will list the hard drive partitions, `help` lists available commands.

Once you have set the root correctly you can `ls /` to view files and directories to find the correct path to the windows boot manager if it is not in the default location.

Comment: Make sure to use the `ls` command for checking the name of your partition, because it might not be `(hd0,gpt1)`. With using the proper partition name I was able to fix Windows booting, thanks to your answer.

Comment: This works but I have to run these commands every time I boot the system. It there any way to make it permanent.

Comment: @rupindr You need to edit /etc/grub.d/##_***** where ##_***** is the file containing your configuration, after that remember to do a **update-grub**

Comment: If `EFI file not found` after `chainloader` , then search location of bootmgfw.efi (I searched on another computer via Linux, looks like can use `search` in grub).

Answer (score 57):

Just enter the command `exit`. It should take you to another menu that makes you select the Windows bootloader.

Worked on Lenovo Y50

Comment: **Worked well** on HP i5 7th Gen with **Win10** after formatting the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Glad it helped! @Elshan

Comment: Worked in Lenovo ThinkPad, never expected it will work

Comment: Worked in Lenovo IdeaPad

Comment: Works with Dell Inspiron 7559

Comment: "exit" just brings me back to the GNU GRUB menu where I choose the different boot systems (Ubuntu or Windows XP in my case) or press c for the grub command-line. I want to get to the msdos command prompt instead.

Comment: +Microsoft Surface pro tablet/laptop

Answer (score 13):

To boot to Windows, if Windows is installed on first drive/partition, enter in `grub` command line, then boot:

```
insmod chain
insmod ntfs
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader +1
boot
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html#Chain_002dloading for more details.

Comment: This applies only if the Windows system disk is using MBR partitioning. For the GPT equivalent, see [this answer by @79E09796](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429352/258991)

Comment: How can you tell which partition exactly to set as the root? What if it's not (hd0,1)?

Comment: @einpoklum, the partition with Windows, need to know which partition it is. May boot liveUSB Linux distro to check. Worked for me. Do `ls` in grub command to see a list to check names.

Answer (score 9):

Guesing you have an UEFI device, the windows bootloader is still installed. You can select it back in UEFI setup menu under boot, where you will prbably have two options (GRUB and the old default as the second), delete the first one or switch the order.

Comment: I had to restart at least one time until this worked. The first time I tried `exit`, it told me that some file wasn't found. But on the second attempt, it worked

Answer (score 8):

> **This answer is for those with UEFI who have deleted the Ubuntu partitions before removing grub**

You will be doing this from Windows 10. No bootable media required.

Where `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootsect /nt60` and the Ubuntu live with the `boot-repair` suggestions have failed, this has worked for me:

(This answer borrowed verbatim from [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/))

1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
2. Run `diskpart`
3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk
5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory

Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the black grub screen.

Copied from https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Great! working!

Answer (score 2):

Just exit the `grub` by typing `exit` and go to bios setup and restore to default settings and restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bumped into the same problem. (i.e. originally have a a separate partition with Ubuntu installed, dual bootable from a grub menu. I then deleted that Ubuntu partition from Windows disk management, and when I rebooted, just the grub command menu).

What I did to get back to my Windows 10:

1. Do a `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Delete` to reboot. While rebooting, hold down the `shift` button.
2. My PC then give me to option to press `F12` for boot option. I clicked `F12`, and it gives me back a menu with Windows boot manager on it.
3. I selected the Windows boot manager and click enter. I'm now back to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me, now I have to find a way to permanently fix the mbr.

I recently bumped into the same problem. (i.e. originally have a a separate partition with Ubuntu installed, dual bootable from a grub menu. I then deleted that Ubuntu partition from Windows disk management, and when I rebooted, just the grub command menu).

What I did to get back to my Windows 10:

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to reboot. While rebooting, hold down the shift button.
My PC then give me to option to press <kbd>F12</kbd> for boot option. I clicked <kbd>F12</kbd>, and it gives me back a menu with Windows boot manager on it.
I selected the Windows boot manager and click <kbd>enter</kbd>. I'm now back to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its worked in my case:

```
grub> exit
```

You will get a list of operating systems installed. Select one.

Comment: Already answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403149/245871

Comment: ... and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486730/377345

Comment: worked for me this

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
makeactive
boot
```