# System boots into GRUB when no Ubuntu is present

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub, gnu

I've installed Ubuntu on dualboot a few months ago but decided that today I'd uninstall it due to some problems. I foolishly just went into Windows and deleted the partition Ubuntu was in, then rebooted. Now, I'm greeted with a GNU GRUB screen.

I tried typing exit but it just reloads the GRUB screen. I tried changing my boot order but there is only ubuntu on the list, no windows anywhere. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a windows partition from the Grub command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259069/how-to-start-a-windows-partition-from-the-grub-command-line)

Comment: UEFI or BIOS as procedures are a lot different. Best just to use your Windows repair disk and run Windows repairs, particularly fixMBR, but maybe fixBOOT & chkdsk.

Comment: @oldfred The fact that the boot order list says "ubuntu" strongly suggests UEFI: on most traditional BIOSes you cannot have custom names for your OSs within the BIOS bootloader list, while with UEFI it's a standard feature.

Comment: Not sure if OP is seeing UEFI boot screen or grub menu. UEFI boot screen should also show Windows unless erased. Grub will not show Windows if fast start up is on or Windows has other issues whether BIOS or UEFI.May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems before and just about everytime 
"Super Grub Disk" (or SGD2) was a helpful tool... (you find it here https://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

Another workable way would be to run a linux live cd (or usb) and edit the 
config files for GRUB manually (since i am not at all certain if "update-grub" would be working in this case) to show only Windows as an entry (as opposed to only Ubuntu).

When I used it last time Super Grub Disk was able to remove GRUB entirely and restore the Windows Bootloader which I guess is what you want from what you expressed... So I would give this a try personally. 
Otherwise as already suggested by others using a Windows repair disc may do the trick as well.