# Dual Booting Windows 10 + Debian problems

Tags: linux, debian, windows, dual-boot

I wanted to make a dual boot for the first time in my life with my already installed windows 10 and a new Debian 8.3 system.
(Note: I have 2 harddrives, one for the windows system and the other one would go for the debian installation)
I made a bootable USB, booted onto it, installed the system without connection to the internet (for some reason I couldnt connect over WIFI), then when i was asked where to place the GRUB I put it on the Windows drive by accident.
After the installation it tried to boot into debian but it was stuck on a message that looked like this: Debian fsck from linux util something. 
A pic of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd2ex.jpg 
Restarted the computer after 20 min it was like that stuck and I got into the GRUB loader and to my surprise I couldnt spot my windows, only Debian.
I thought maybe if I disconnect the SATA connector of the Debian harddrive windows might load and of course I was wrong and it went into GRUB rescue.

Now I have no idea what to do further since I have almost no knowledge in Linux.
I reckon that I need to get the windows boot loader back up.
Any thoughts on how I can boot into my windows system and fix this entire mess?

After running `lsblk` and `sudo blkid` I recieved this:
http://pastebin.com/HEVyRui5

Comment: log onto the debian and run `lsblk` and `sudo blkid` and add the contents to your post.

Comment: @Liam I pretty much can't even logon to debian. Check the image link I shared on the main post.

Comment: Try using a linux live usb (any distro). Use BIOS to boot to the usb.

Comment: @Liam http://pastebin.com/HEVyRui5 here is a paste with the contents.

Comment: you had a 1TB drive that had windows on it and an empty 500GB drive that you were putting debian on?

Comment: @Liam Yes. I formated the Debian hard drive(500gb) since I thought it might let me boot into windows again. I was wrong. I would just be happy to reinstall windows now but it dosent let me since the hard drive is MBR and it must be GPT. I would convert it to GPT through the command line but it means there will be data loss, and I don't want the "Dev Drive" partition formatted. Any idea how i can change it through ubuntu?

Comment: "I would just be happy to reinstall windows now"
Does that mean you're willing to start entirely fresh? Because that should be relatively easy.

Comment: You can use a Windows rescue or installation disk to fix this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the Debian boot is that the graphics card is not being loaded correctly, it is missing some firmware. Once you fix that you can boot into Debian and fix your Grub.

To fix your Debian boot, go into Safe Mode at the Grub boot, that should not load your graphics driver and just give you a text console. From there log in as root, edit `/etc/apt/sources.conf`, add `non-free` to your Debian package repository. It should look something like this:

```
deb http://my mirror/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://my mirror/debian/ jessie main
```

issue `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` reboot if everything went well and you should be able to boot into Debian just fine.

Then to fix Grub after that, open a terminal when you logged into Debian and get root privelages, run `os-prober` which should detect your windows partition and then run `update-grub`.