# Fix grub rescue mode

Tags: grub

I have windows 10 on my PC. After a while I install lubuntu and dual boot it. I really hate lubuntu so delete the partition and shut down the PC. When I open it I stacked at grub rescue mode. I tried a lot like install windows from bootable usbe but I have secure boot so I was unable, anyone please help me.

Comment: Do the answers to this question help you?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt?rq=1

Comment: Installing OSes, especially in multi-boot configurations, require an understanding of the boot process and **familiarity with the specific firmware - BIOS or UEFI - in your computer**.